# How to extract the middle item or (Two Items in Middle) from an array regardless of Odd or Even Number of Items?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I extract middle item from odd number of elements:

```
var givenArray = ['Maths','English', 'Social', 'Economics','Tech']
console.log(givenArray[((givenArray.length-1)/2)])
```

It provides output to be `social` which is what I am expecting but in case the number of items is even :

```
var givenArray = ['Maths','English', 'Social', 'Economics']
console.log(givenArray[((givenArray.length)/2)])
```

I get output `Social`.

The actual question here is, How can I access the middle item (2 middle items if it's odd) without worrying to get `Undefined` as output regardless of the number of items being odd or even.

I could do that by using conditional statements but I don't want to do so. is there any other way?

P.S: I'm a beginner.

Comment: With an even number of items, what does "middle" mean to you?

Comment: to get 2 of the items laying in the middle?

Comment: Under what circumstance are you getting `Undefined` (with a capital "U" - could just be a mistake in the question, so also `undefined`)?

Comment: var givenArray = ['Maths','English', 'Social', 'Economics','Tech']
console.log(givenArray[givenArray.length/2])

Comment: Please include the *expected* result for M,E,S,E.   You've stated you get "S" but not what you *want* to get (in the question).  Your comment implies you want *two results* when even - is that the case?  Please [edit] the question.

Comment: Ok, I was confused as you stated: *I get output Social as output.* (when even) but appears you get undefined as /2 is not a whole number.

Comment: ```console.log(givenArray[(parseInt((givenArray.length)/2))])```

Comment: Equally `console.log(givenArray[Math.round(givenArray.length/2)])` or other Math. methods that round to nearsest int.

Comment: Figure out first how you would get the result you want **without a computer**. What decisions would you make? How would you represent or explain the result?

Comment: Surely "*2 middle items if it's odd*" should be ... if it's even?

Comment: If you want 1 value in one case and 2 values in another case, then you will need an `if` (or other conditional constructs such as `?:` or even .filter) as you're getting different *types* of value back (string vs array of string)

Comment: FYI @Yogi 's solution to use `Arrray.at` does remove the issue of getting `undefined` without any additional work as it automatically coerces the index to a number (without needing to floor/ceil/round):   instead of `givenArray[givenArray.length/2]` use `givenArray.at(givenArray.length/2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer

To receive the 2 middle Items without using a conditional you can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), `Set`'s are a collection of unique values.

#### Even Example

```js
const evenArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

// 4 divided by 2 is 2, 2 floored is 2
const indexA = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
// 4 divided by 2 is 2, 2 ceiled is 2, 2 minus 1 is 1
const indexB = Math.ceil (array.length / 2 - 1);
// so indexA is 2, and indexB is 1, the 2 middle 

const resultSet = new Set()

// add the values, if we add the same values twice no problem, the set deduplicates them
resultSet.add(evenArray[indexA] ?? defaultValue)
resultSet.add(evenArray[indexB] ?? defaultValue)

// logs ["B", "C"]
console.log([...resultSet])
```

#### Odd Example

```js
const oddArray = ["A", "B", "C"];

// 3 divided by 2 is 1.5, 1.5 floored is 1
const indexA = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
// 3 divided by 2 is 1.5, 1.5 ceiled is 2, 2 minus 1 is 1
const indexB = Math.ceil (array.length / 2 - 1);
// so indexA is 1, and indexB is 1, the middle 

const resultSet = new Set()

// add the values, if we add the same values twice no problem, the set deduplicates them
resultSet.add(evenArray[indexA] ?? defaultValue)
resultSet.add(evenArray[indexB] ?? defaultValue)

// logs ["B"]
console.log([...resultSet])
```

I do not recommend doing it this way as the code is overly complex and hard to read, but as a mental gymnastic it is fine ;-D

### Old Answer

You can use [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) or [Math.ceil()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor):

```js
const arrOdd     = ["A", "B", "C"]
const arrEven    = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

// length is 3, divided by 2 is 1.5, floored it becomes 1
const outputOdd  = Math.floor(arrOdd.length / 2)

// length is 4, divided by 2 is 2, floored it becomes 2
const outputEven = Math.floor(arrEven.length / 2)
```

That's how you avoid invalid array indexes, but an array might include undefined in the middle like so:

```js
const meanArray = ["A", undefined, "C"]
```

with our previous method we would get undefined, even though the index is correct.

To fix this you would use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) `??` to assign a default value.

To combine everything, we now have:

```js
const defaultValue = "Technology"
console.log(givenArray[Math.floor(((givenArray.length)/2))] ?? defaultValue)
```

Comment: This is fine code but it doesn't answer the (weird) requirements of the updated question.

Comment: @Pointy I wanted one middle item if the index is whole number else I wanted two items that lies in the middle.

Comment: @Pointy that is correct, just read the update, time to update the answer .... :)

Comment: Nice use of `new Set()` and taking advantage of adding the same value doesn't add it twice (without giving an error which happens in other languages/collection types).  Looks more complicated than it is just due to the code comments but is really only 3 lines.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you

> need 1 result when odd an 2 results when even

the solution is to return an array (so that you get the same "type" of result each time) - you can combine/join this as you like after.

One issue is that indexes are (generally) 0-based, so .length for 5 items is 5 and 5/2 is 2.5, not the expected *3* for the 3rd item.

Here's a solution using .filter.  This compares the 1-based current index with the 1-based length/2 rounded both up and down - so when 2.5 it gives positions 2 and 3.

In practice, I would just add an `if`, but the requirement is to not use "conditional statements" (up to you if .filter and `||` count as conditional statements).

```js
function getMiddleValue(givenArray) {
  return givenArray.filter((word, idx) =>
    (idx + 1) == Math.floor((givenArray.length + 1) / 2) ||
    (idx + 1) == Math.ceil((givenArray.length + 1) / 2));
}

var givenArray = ['Maths', 'English', 'Social', 'Economics', 'Tech']
console.log(getMiddleValue(givenArray));

var givenArray = ['Maths', 'English', 'Social', 'Economics']
console.log(getMiddleValue(givenArray));
```

Alternatively, pre-determine the 2 indices - these will have the same value when odd, by using .filter, it will only return one value, not two when they are the same

```js
function getMiddleValue(givenArray) {
  var idx1 = Math.floor((givenArray.length + 1) / 2) - 1;
  var idx2 = Math.ceil((givenArray.length + 1) / 2) - 1
  return givenArray.filter((word, idx) => idx == idx1 || idx == idx2);
}

var givenArray = ['Maths', 'English', 'Social', 'Economics', 'Tech']
console.log(getMiddleValue(givenArray));

var givenArray = ['Maths', 'English', 'Social', 'Economics']
console.log(getMiddleValue(givenArray));
```

Comment: @Yogi Didn't get a chance to comment: nice use of `Array.at` which I (tbh) didn't know about before.  Yes, the question was/is a bit of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do that with roundof. No need to check for even or odd.

```js
var givenArray=['Maths','English', 'Social', 'Economics'];
console.log(givenArray[Math.round((givenArray.length-1)/2)])
```

Comment: Seems simple than floor or ceil functions & exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Not seeing how this gives you both "English" *and* "Social" for the given array.

Comment: FYI: Across languages (not just js), for positive numbers:  Math.floor always rounds down, Math.ceil always rounds up while Math.round rounds in which ever direction the implementation decided based on whether they were having a bad Monday.  In some cases, odd.5 rounds up while even.5 rounds down (1.5->2, 2.5->2).

Comment: @freedomn-m yep, not 2 values but at lest solves 'undefined' problem. Twiggeh has to something about that!

Comment: and you too do so..